# Which nonlinear Observer to study to estimate the speed of the Plant?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics, parameter-estimation

I have designed the mathematical model of the plant with nonlinear hystersis function $f(x_1)$ and is validated using simulation. Now I want to design the nonlinear observer to estimate the speed (that is $x_2$). Not that I have also modeled the nonlinear function $f(x_1)$ in the model.
My state space model of the plant is
$$\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}_1 & = x_2;\\
\dot{x}_2 & = q*x_1 + c*x_2 + f(x_1) + u.
\end{aligned}
$$
Please suggest suitable observer with known nonlinearity to estimate the angular speed $x_2$.
$x_1$ is the angular position of the plant.
$q$ and $c$ are constants.

Comment: I assume $x_1$ is measured?

Comment: This might have poor robustness to disturbances and model inaccuracies, but you could try [linearized error dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_observer#Linearizable_error_dynamics).

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen van der Veen Yes x1 is measured. I assumed no disturbance and inaccuracy in model. Just it have nonlinearity which also I have modeled. Now I want to estimate the x2. Which Observer should I choose with known nonlinearity. Thnx

Comment: How do you model hysteresis? Namely, often it is a function of the history of $x_1$, thus one can directly do linearized error dynamics.

Comment: Correction: one can **not** directly do linearized error dynamics.

Comment: I have modeled hysteresis using Maxwell resistive capacitor model.